# show progress when click button Dynamics CRM 365

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, progress

I have a ribbon button to execute custom workflow. this action a setup from JavaScript and it worked perfectly. In this case I wanna show progress loading when after click or during custom workflow execution.

I just followed the tutorial **[HERE](https://mahenderpal.wordpress.com/2012/03/21/show-loading-message-during-function-execution-in-crm-form/)**. this my javascript function code:

```
function showLoadingMessage() {
    try{
        tdAreas.style.display = 'none';
        var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
        newdiv.setAttribute('id', "msgDiv");
        newdiv.valign = "middle";
        newdiv.align = "center";
        var divInnerHTML = "<table height='100%' width='100%' style='cursor:wait'>";
        divInnerHTML += "<tr>";
        divInnerHTML += "<td valign='middle' align='center'>";
        divInnerHTML += "<img alt='' src='/_imgs/AdvFind/progress.gif'/>";
        divInnerHTML += "<div/><b>Working…</b>";
        divInnerHTML += "</td></tr></table>";
        newdiv.innerHTML = divInnerHTML;
        newdiv.style.background = '#FFFFFF';
        newdiv.style.fontSize = "15px";
        newdiv.style.zIndex = "1010";
        newdiv.style.width = document.body.clientWidth;
        newdiv.style.height = document.body.clientHeight;
        newdiv.style.position = 'absolute';
        document.body.insertBefore(newdiv, document.body.firstChild);
        document.all.msgDiv.style.visibility = 'visible';
    }
    catch(ex){
        alert(ex.message);
    }  
}
```

and this one is to hide progress:

```
function hideLoadingMessage(){
    document.all.msgDiv.style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
```

this is the function that I called in my ribbon button action for testing loading progress work or not:

```
function ribbonButton()
{
    var guid = Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId();
    if (guid != null)
    {
        showLoadingMessage(); //show progress

        /*var workflowId = '04E84379-87E4-E711-814E-000C294D2FF8';
        var workflowName = 'CloneReward';
        ExecuteWorkflow(workflowId, workflowName, function ()
        {
            RefreshForm();
        });*/

        //hideLoadingMessage(); //hide progress
    }
}
```

when I pressed the button I get the following error message:

[image]

Need any suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: Where did you declared the `tdAreas` variable ?

Comment: i just following the tutorial that i attached above

Comment: There is a solution in the same tutorial link that you have followed. Did you try that solution ?

Comment: yes, i do. when i change `tdAreas.style.display = 'none';` to be `document.getElementById('tdAreas').parentElement.style.display = 'none';` i still have error: **unable to to get property 'parentElement' of undefined or null reference**. I don't understand what is `tdAreas`

Comment: @KapilBarad finally i looked another tutorial and it work. i have posted answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just tried this [THIS](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/209370) tutorial and it will fix the problem above.

show loading progress:

```
function _buildLoadingDiv(_entityName) {
    var loadingDiv = "<div id='divLoading'style='width: 100%; height: 100%; display: block; position: fixed; top:0px; background:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);'><table style='width: 100%; height: 100%;'><tr><td align='center' style='vertical-align: middle;'>";
    loadingDiv += "<img id='loading' alt='' src='/_imgs/AdvFind/progress.gif'/><br/>";
    loadingDiv += "<label id='lblStatus'>Loading... " + _entityName + " Execute Workflow</label>";
    loadingDiv += "</td></tr></table></div>";

    $($('body', window.parent.document)).append(loadingDiv);
}
```

hide loading progress:

```
function _removeLoading() {
    $($('body', window.parent.document)).find("#divLoading").remove();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is new nice client API for exact this feature: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/clientapi/reference/xrm-utility/showprogressindicator

Here is example on how it looks in work: http://www.itaintboring.com/dynamics-crm/dynamics-365-v9-progress-indicator-api/

The only downside is that it's only applicable to Dynamics version 9.